# Copying a file from one location to another location. Only overwrite the file if the source location is newer. Batch Script

Tags: batch-file

Copying a file from one location to another location. Only overwrite the file if the source location is newer.

```
Set Destination= %userprofile%\Documents\Something
Set Source= \\infra\setupfiles
robocopy %Source% %Destination% programstartup.bat /xo
```

Robocopy skips the file. Even if the file is missing from the Destination.
Any Thoughts Ideas

/xo Excludes older files

[Screenshot from CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57Mc5.png)

Comment: Besides the typo you have in the variable name, it is best practice to not assign leading or trailing spaces to variables unless you really need them. `Set "Destination=%userprofile%\Documents\Something"`

Comment: `/XO` tells `RoboCopy` not to overwrite an existing file in the destination if it is the same date or newer than the source version. I'm also intrigued as to why you're using `/DCopy:DA` when you're only copying a file! There's also no reason why the code you posted, does not match that in your screenshot. Why don't you provide us with a specific issue with a fully replicable task, instead of just posting anything, and hoping that people are willing to try an second guess things.

Answer (score 0):

So if the typo is not it, I guess it could be a format error?
Try this (I tried locally and it works for me):

```
Set Destination="%userprofile%\Documents\Something"
Set Source="\\infra\setupfiles"
robocopy %Source% %Destination% "programstartup.bat" /xo
```

**EDIT:**

From your screenshot I can see there are no files to copy, only a directory. Look closer at the "Files" or "Bytes" row from the screenshot you provided:

[image: Screenshot from OP]

It should look like this:

[image]

You probably do not have access to the file or it doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry fat-fingered it here. That is what I have.

Comment: Here is the result. It's on another system without internet access. It's still skipping the file. Even thou it does not exist in the destination. (Seen ScreenShot I Attached)